# Делаю бота для регистрации на сервере ы дискорде, с помощью discord.py проблема с выдачей роли

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return


    if message.content.startswith("/start"):
        await message.channel.send("Привет, я бот для регистрации на сервере,если ты хочешь зарегистрироваться на сервере, введи команду /reg")


    if message.content.startswith("/reg") or message.content.startswith("/repeat"):

         await message.channel.send("Пожалуйста, введите ваши настоящие имя и фамилию с помощью команды /name.""Например:/name Иванов Иван")
    if message.content.startswith("/name"):
        global s
        s = message.content
        s= s.replace(" ","")
        s= s.replace("/name","")
        s = pytils.translit.translify(s)
        await message.channel.send("Хорошо, ваш логин:"+ s +"  "+"Ваш логин должен полностью соответсвовать вашим имени и фамилии, только записанным на транслите.Если всё верно, то напишите команду /next,если это не так, введите команду /repeat")
    if message.content.startswith("/next"):
        alphabet ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

        password =random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(alphabet)
        #На этом моменте, данные должны записаться в базу


        await message.channel.send("Ваши данные записаны! Ваш логин:"+ s + "Ваш пароль:" + password +".Теперь вам доступны все чаты на сервере в дискорде и вход в мир.")
        author = message.author # получаем автора сообщения
        guild = self.get_guild(config.Server_ID) # получаем объект сервера*
        role = guild.get_role(config.GamerRole_ID) # получаем объект роли*
        await author.add_roles(role) # выдаем автору роль
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.API_TOKEN)
```

Когда я пишу команды прямо на сервере, всё работает и роль выдаётся. Но бот должен работать в личных сообщениях т.к. он выдаёт личную информацию о пользователе(пароль и логин).Есть ли возможность выдавать роль прямо из личных сообщений или сделать это невозможно?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить роль в личном сообщении невозожно, но можно написать эти сообщения лично возможно. Нужно написать `message.author.send("сообщение")`

Comment: Спасибо, сам уже до этого дошёл)